# Кастомный формат времени и учёт склонения

Tags: c#

Допустим мне нужно получить значение даты
"Понедельник 1 апреля"

На данный момент я делаю так:

```
var ponedelnik = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
var day  = (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
var month = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM");
```

получается:

```
"понедельник 1 апрель"
```

Да в принципе я могу просклонять месяц, сделать первую букву дня недели с большой буквы и т.д. Есть ли более элегантное решение? Может я тут свой велосипед строю?

Comment: @AK а все вместе не бывает?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Не надо всё по отдельности делать, форматируйте сразу:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU");
var date = DateTime.Today;
date.ToString("dddd d MMMM", culture).Dump();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. [Строки настраиваемых форматов даты и времени](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

О склонении. В каждой культуре есть есть два массива:

```
cultureRu.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames.Dump();
cultureRu.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames.Dump();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом выводится имя месяца именно в генитиве (родительный падеж) - января, февраля и т.п.

А вот если бы вам понадобилось склонять день недели - то такое не предусмотрено в настройках локалей, только номинатив (именительный падеж).

С заглавной тоже придётся самостоятельно (string.ToUpper, TextInfo.ToTitleCase) разбираться.

В принципе, вам ничего не мешает определить свой собственный [форматтер времени](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Чисто в качестве иллюстрации. Допустим, вам нужна фраза "к понедельнику" или вы хотите сделать "понедельник" с большой буквы. Можно создать копию культуры и в ней поменять формат дней недели.

```
var cultureRu = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU");
cultureRu.DateTimeFormat.DayNames = new string[] {"Понедельнику", "Вторнику", "Среде", "Четвергу", "Пятнице", "Субботе", "Воскресенью" };

var date = DateTime.Today;
date.ToString("к dddd d MMMM", cultureRu).Dump();
```

Выведет: "к Вторнику 15 апреля"

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы вместо "1 январь 2023" получать "1 января 2023", и чтобы вместо "1 май" получать "1 мая", нужно использовать такой код:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames = culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames;
culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = culture.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames;
string result1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("d MMMM yyyy", culture);
string result2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("d MMM", culture);
```