# Как вывести месяц с окончанием? (например: января, декабря)

Tags: c#

У меня есть DTO - DayDto, объект выглядит вот так:

```
internal record CalendarDto(
    List<DayDto> Days,
    short Year,
    List<HolidayDto> Holidays);

internal record DayDto(
    DateTime? Day,
    DateTime? From,
    string Type,
    string Holiday);

internal record HolidayDto(
    int Id,
    string Title);
```

Моя задача: отформатировать дни. Ожидаемый результат:

- Новогодние каникулы - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 **января**
- Рождество Христово - 7 **января**

Обратите еще, пожалуйста, внимание на то, что я вставляю месяц только в конец перечисления дней.
Вот такой код для форматирования я написал:

```
private IEnumerable<(string Title, string Date)> GetFormattedHolidays(CalendarDto calendarDto)
{
    foreach(var holiday in calendarDto.Holidays)
    {
        var grouped = calendarDto.Days
           .Where(dayDto => dayDto.Holidays == holiday.Id.ToString())
           .GroupBy(dayDto => dayDto.Day.Value.Month)
           .Select(group =>
              $"{string.Join(", ", group.Select(dayDto => dayDto.Day?.Day))}"+
              $"{_context.Culture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(group.Key)}")
           .ToArray();

        yield return ($"{holiday.Title}", $"{grouped.JoinToString( ", " )}");
    }
}
```

Проблема вся в том, что я получаю следующее:

- Новогодние каникулы - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 **январь**
- Рождество Христово - 7 **январь**

Т.е окончание у месяца исчезает, как мне это исправить?

Comment: `_context.Culture.DateTimeFormat.MonthGenitiveNames[int monthIndex]` ?

Comment: Похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/969753/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Не знал о таком, спасибо!